# C string splitting with strtok by newline character error

Tags: c, string, parsing, compiler-errors

I run into a problem with splitting a string by the new line character.

The idea is that the server is sending to a client a message and the client splits the message by newline character in other 2 strings

I get a segmentation fault error.

This is the client section where it receives, splits and outputs the result.

```
    char response[256];

    rc = read(sockfd, &response, 256);

    printf("The response is: %s\n", response);//prints the string in 2 lines

    char * pch;
    pch = strtok (response, "\n");

    printf("Part 1 -> %s\n\n", pch); // ERROR

    pch = strtok (NULL, "\n");
    printf("Part 2 -> %s\n\n", pch);
```

The error message shows:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: post your exact seg fault output

Comment: you can't post the seg fault dump?

Comment: I don't see sockfd initialization part, it can be causes by that.

Comment: Socket and the communication between server and client work fine, I just omitted the part of the code which is not related the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chances are that (a) `response` is not initialized and (b) the `read()` function did not get to read a terminating null in the string.  To demonstrate, use:

```
int rc = read(sockfd, response, sizeof(response));

printf("The response is: %.*\n", rc, response);
```

You should really check that `rc` is neither negative (a read failure) nor zero (EOF) before using it in the `printf()` statement, and you need to null terminate before passing it to `strtok()` et al, so maybe a better treatment is:

```
int rc = read(sockfd, response, sizeof(response)-1);

if (rc <= 0)
    ...error or EOF...

response[rc] = '\0';
```

---

> I still get the error...

You've marked the code where the error occurs at:

```
char *pch;
pch = strtok(response, "\n");

printf("Part 1 -> %s\n\n", pch); // ERROR
```

The most plausible reason for a core dump there is that `pch` contains a null pointer.  So, to protect yourself, test the result from `strtok()`:

```
char *pch = strtok(response, "\n");

if (pch == 0)
    printf("strtok() failed\n");
else
    printf("Part 1 -> %s\n\n", pch);
```

You should make sure that if `pch` is null, you don't continue using it.

You didn't show the declaration of `rc`; if it was `unsigned char rc`, then the 255 value might indicate a -1 returned from the `read()` call.

Also, the code I showed assumes that the definition of `response()` is visible as an array (either at file scope or function scope, not as a parameter to a function).  When the array is a function parameter, `sizeof(response)` returns the same value as `sizeof(char *)`, which is not the size of the array in general.

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
rc = read(sockfd, &response, 256);
```

with

```
rc = read(sockfd, response, 256);
```

`response` is already a pointer to your buffer.

Comment: o god I overlooked the response declaration this whole time. yes this is the problem

Comment: I think that `&response` and `response` point to the same location, though the types are different (`char (*)[256]` vs `char *`).  If that's correct, the change won't affect the segmentation fault.  (Don't get me wrong: the `&` should not be there.  However, it probably isn't the source of the segmentation fault this time.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is right, and although conceptually omittin the adressof operator is the good solution, here this doesn't fix the problem (nor should it).